# Change an element of an array using a for loop in Python

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop

I'm trying to teach myself Python and am doing some menial tasks with it. At the minute I'm working with lists and strings. I know that strings are immutable so I'm converting a string to a list and want to loop over the list to change any vowels to $ signs. The problem is that the $ sign isn't being attributed to the vowels. Here is my code:

```
aString = raw_input("Please enter a sentence: ")

aString = list(aString)

for i in xrange(len(aString)):
    if i=='a' or \
       i=='e' or \
       i=='i' or \
       i=='o' or \
       i=='u':
        i.newattribute = '$'

print aString
```

Comment: xrange generates integers, rather than characters :-)

Comment: @MaksymPolshcha Thanks for that. Have to do a bit more research into loops etc in Python. There's a lot to them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know you are doing it to learn the language, but you should know you could simply use the method `sub` to substitute with a regular expression:

```
import re
re.sub('[aeiou]', '$', aString)
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to do the following:

```
for i in xrange(len(aString)):
    if aString[i]=='a' or \
       aString[i]=='e' or \
       aString[i]=='i' or \
       aString[i]=='o' or \
       aString[i]=='u':
          aString[i] = '$'
```

But it would probably be easier to use the replace method.

```
replaceList = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
aString = raw_input("Please enter a sentence: ")
for letter in replaceList:
    aString.replace(letter)
print aString
```

Comment: The replace function is something that I haven't seen before. Thanks for that Niek. Python is full of these new functions that I haven't seen before. I'm only familiar with C and C++

Answer (score 2):

```
strs="abcduitryd"
print("".join(('$' if x in 'aeiou' else x for x in strs)))

$bcd$$tryd
```

**or:**

```
strs="abcduitryd"
lis=list(strs)
for i,x in enumerate(lis):
    if x in 'aeiou':
        lis[i]='$'
strs="".join(lis)
print(strs)

$bcd$$tryd
```

**or :**

```
strs="abcduitryd"
for i,x in enumerate(strs):
    if x in 'aeiou':
        strs=strs.replace(strs[i],'$')
print(strs)

$bcd$$tryd
```

Comment: you don't have to `list()` the string. a string is an iterable.

Comment: oh! i forgot to remove that line, when I copied this from the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

The "Pythonic" way is to use the translate method for string.
example:

```
import string
mystr="hello world"
vowels="aeiou"
token="$"*len(vowels)
tab=string.maketrans(vowels,token)
mystr.translate(tab)
'h$ll$ w$rld'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are learning python, one cool feature that can be used is a list comprehension.  You can do this:

```
>>> str = "hello world"
>>> l = ["$" if ch in "aeiou" else ch for ch in str]
>>> str = "".join(l)
>>> str
'h$ll$ w$rld'
```

The second line builds a list, walking through each character and applying `"$" if ch in "aeiou" else ch1 to it.  You then just join the list to get a new string.  It's doing exactly what you are trying to do, converting the string to a list and in the process, coverting vowels to '$'.

This is not the most efficient way to do it of course.  The best way to do it is to use a library meant for this sort of thing as others have mentioned.

Comment: You don't really need to make a separate list, you can just change that to a generator expression and put it right inside `"".join()`.